# Expo. React Native. Deep links do not work on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, deep-linking

Universal links on iOS work well.
I have an issue with Android.
Please see assetlinks and intentFilters.
I will appreciate any help.
SDK Version: 35.0.0

assetlinks - https://ocov.us/.well-known/assetlinks.json

```
"intentFilters": [
    {
      "action": "VIEW",
      "autoVerify": true,
      "data": {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "*.ocov.us"
      },
      "category": [
        "BROWSABLE",
        "DEFAULT"
      ]
  }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing with `data.host` helped.

Comment: Hi @vasyl, what exactly did you change or do please? I am having same issues

Comment: @MichaelAshefor what helped is duplicate host on this way
`"host": "example.com"` and `"host": "*.example.com"`